# DynamoDB Triggers (Streams + Lambda) : details on TRIM_HORIZON?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, iot

I want to process recent updates on a DynamoDB table and save them in another one. Let's say I get updates from an IoT device irregularly put in Table1, and I need to use the N last updates to compute an update in Table2 for the same device in sync with the original updates (kind of a sliding window).

DynamoDB Triggers (Streams + Lambda) seem quite appropriate for my needs, but I did not find a clear definition of `TRIM_HORIZON`. In some docs I understand that it is the oldest data in Table1 (can get huge), but in other docs it would seems that it is 24h. Or maybe the oldest in the stream, which is 24h?

So anyone knows the truth about `TRIM_HORIZON`? Would it even be possible to configure it?

The alternative I see is not to use `TRIM_HORIZON`, but rather tu use `LATEST` and perform a query on Table1. But it sort of defeats the purpose of streams.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are the relevant aspects for you, from DynamoDB's documentation ([1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) and [2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dynamodbstreams/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html)):

- > All data in DynamoDB Streams is subject to a 24 hour lifetime. You can
  >   retrieve and analyze the last 24 hours of activity for any given table
- > TRIM_HORIZON - Start reading at the last (untrimmed) stream record,
  >   which is the oldest record in the shard. In DynamoDB Streams, there is
  >   a 24 hour limit on data retention. Stream records whose age exceeds
  >   this limit are subject to removal (trimming) from the stream.

So, if you have a Lambda that is continuously processing stream updates, I'd suggest going with `LATEST`.

Also, since you "need to use the N last updates to compute an update in Table2", you will have to query Table1 for every update, so that you can 'merge' the current update with the previous ones for that device. I don't think you can't get around that using `TRIM_HORIZON` too.

Comment: @FrançoisLegras is it possible to increase the dynamodb stream retention from 24hrs to 48hrs?

Comment: @NidhinDavid, I don't think so.

Comment: If you want to increase data retention, I think you can have a lambda copy over data from DDB streams and put it in KinesisData Streams as it can have extended retention up to 7 days (https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/pricing/)

Comment: If you use latest then you will end up with data in an incorrect order. Newest changes will be written first and oldest changes will be written last. So you would end up with stale data, if you are trying to keep both tables in sync. Use `TRIM_HORIZON` to preserve the ordering.

Comment: @DollarAkshay  once we have full data copied and if we need only CDC changes LATEST should be good. TRIM_HORIZON  wouldn't it overwrite if any data is already part (full dump)?